# Project properties not showing in Eclipse LUNA

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-luna

I am using eclipse LUNA.. I am trying to open the project properties after selecting the project and nothing is showing and also right click the project shows broken. 
[image]options

Comment: we also faced this problem, what we done was upgrading to eclipse mars...

Comment: als a similar case [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/361040/eclipse-menus-are-cut-off-or-dont-show)

Comment: Thanks.. I'll upgrade to eclipse mars